# How do you say "I worked for [X company]."?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

The context is you're casually telling a person where you've worked in the past.

I was thinking something like: `IBMで働いた` or `IBMで仕事した`.

But it didn't seem right. In English, the conversation would go something like:

> A: Where did you used to work?
>
> B: I've worked for IBM. And also, I've worked at Best Buy.

Answer (score 4):

`〜で働いた` is fine for literally "worked at".  But I more often hear `〜に[勤]{つと}める` meaning "employed for/by 〜"; usually in the `〜ている` form ("am currently employed for/by 〜").  In this case, I think you'd just use the simple past tense.

> IBMに勤めたことがある。そして、BestBuyにも。

Also, see this post about a unique employment situation:  [Employed by one institution but work for another](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6157/78).

Comment: Is there a difference between using で働いた or に働いた? Any nuances? And you could use で勤つとめる or would that be strange sounding?

Comment: "IBMで働いた", "IBMに勤めた", and "IBMで勤めた" are all correct, but "IBMに働いた" is wrong. (don't ask me why, please).

Comment: I've never heard `〜で勤める`, and it sounds incorrect to my ear, but that's not to say it is.

Comment: Googling gives many good examples of "～で勤める", though I agree it's less common than "～に勤める".

Answer (score 3):

In casual conversation I think you can say:

> A: (前は)どこ(orどこの会社)にいたの？/いたんですか。
> B: ((ずっと)前(は))IBMにいた/いました。あと、BestBuyにもいた/いました/いたことがあります。etc.

... using the verb いる(居る), or

> A: (前は)どこに(orどこの会社に/どこに仕事(に)/仕事(は)どこ(に))行ってたの？/行ってたんですか。
> B: ((ずっと)前(は))IBMに行ってた/行ってました。あと、BestBuyにも行ってた/行ってました/行ってたことがあります。etc.

... using the verb 行く. 
Of course you can say:

> A: どこに勤めてたの？/勤めてたんですか。
> B: IBMに勤めてた/勤めてました/勤めてたことがあります。etc.
>
> A: どこで働いてたの？/働いてたんですか。
> B: IBMで働いてた/働いてました/働いてたことがあります。etc.

... using 勤める/働く. I think using いる/行く would be more colloquial.